# Implementing Android 6.0 permissions in unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, permissions

I've installed Android Support Library but in the developer.android site says that for implementing it on my project I need to edit my build.gradle file that I don't have because it's an Unity project.

I've created a build.gradle file copying the content of this website: http://gradleplease.appspot.com/ and I put that file on the root of my Unity project but when I try to use the library it does not work

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                                      Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
                                                            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                                          new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add the permissions directly in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: It's Android 6.0 Marshmallow. That doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 27):

You need Java code to ask for permission, and you need an interface into said Java code from Unity's C# runtime. You need to create a [Unity Plugin](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html) to do this.

Below is the plugin that I've created to grant the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission at runtime.

You need a project structure like this:

```
Plugins/
  Android/
    NoodlePermissionGranter/
      project.properties
      AndroidManifest.xml
      NoodlePermissionGranter.cs
      libs/
        NoodlePermissionGranter.jar
```

NoodlePermissionGranter.cs:

```
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     ///////////////// NoodlePermissionGranter /////////////////
    /// Implements runtime granting of Android permissions. ///
   /// This is necessary for Android M (6.0) and above. //////
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   
 //////////////////// Noodlecake Studios ///////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class NoodlePermissionGranter : MonoBehaviour {

    // subscribe to this callback to see if your permission was granted.
    public static Action<bool> PermissionRequestCallback;

    // for now, it only implements the external storage permission
    public enum NoodleAndroidPermission
    {
        WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    }
    public static void GrantPermission(NoodleAndroidPermission permission) 
    {
        if (!initialized)
            initialize ();

        noodlePermissionGranterClass.CallStatic ("grantPermission", activity, (int)permission);
    }







      //////////////////////////////
     /// Initialization Stuff /////
    //////////////////////////////

    // it's a singleton, but no one needs to know about it. hush hush. dont touch me.
    private static NoodlePermissionGranter instance;
    private static bool initialized = false;

    public void Awake()
    {
        // instance is also set in initialize.
        // having it here ensures this thing doesnt break
        // if you added this component to the scene manually
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad (this.gameObject);
        // object name must match UnitySendMessage call in NoodlePermissionGranter.java
        if (name != NOODLE_PERMISSION_GRANTER)
            name = NOODLE_PERMISSION_GRANTER;
    }


    private static void initialize()
    {
        // runs once when you call GrantPermission

        // add object to scene
        if (instance == null) {
            GameObject go = new GameObject();
            // instance will also be set in awake, but having it here as well seems extra safe
            instance = go.AddComponent<NoodlePermissionGranter>();
            // object name must match UnitySendMessage call in NoodlePermissionGranter.java
            go.name = NOODLE_PERMISSION_GRANTER; 
        }

        // get the jni stuff. we need the activty class and the NoodlePermissionGranter class.
        noodlePermissionGranterClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.noodlecake.unityplugins.NoodlePermissionGranter");
        AndroidJavaClass u3d = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        activity = u3d.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("currentActivity");

        initialized = true;
    }







      ///////////////////
     //// JNI Stuff ////
    ///////////////////

    static AndroidJavaClass noodlePermissionGranterClass;
    static AndroidJavaObject activity;
    private const string WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE="WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE";
    private const string PERMISSION_GRANTED = "PERMISSION_GRANTED"; // must match NoodlePermissionGranter.java
    private const string PERMISSION_DENIED = "PERMISSION_DENIED"; // must match NoodlePermissionGranter.java
    private const string NOODLE_PERMISSION_GRANTER = "NoodlePermissionGranter"; // must match UnitySendMessage call in NoodlePermissionGranter.java

    private void permissionRequestCallbackInternal(string message)
    {
        // were calling this method from the java side.
        // the method name and gameobject must match NoodlePermissionGranter.java's UnitySendMessage
        bool permissionGranted = (message == PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        if (PermissionRequestCallback != null)
            PermissionRequestCallback (permissionGranted);
    }
}
```

NoodlePermissionGranter.java:

```
package com.noodlecake.unityplugins;


      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     ///////////////// NoodlePermissionGranter /////////////////
    /// Implements runtime granting of Android permissions. ///
   /// This is necessary for Android M (6.0) and above. //////
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   
 //////////////////// Noodlecake Studios ///////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

import android.Manifest;
import android.os.Build;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import java.io.File;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;

public class NoodlePermissionGranter
{
    // Only implements WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE so far.
    // Implement the rest by matching the enum in NoodlePermissionGranter.cs
    // to the getPermissionStringFromEnumInt below.

    private final static String UNITY_CALLBACK_GAMEOBJECT_NAME = "NoodlePermissionGranter";
    private final static String UNITY_CALLBACK_METHOD_NAME = "permissionRequestCallbackInternal";
    private final static String PERMISSION_GRANTED = "PERMISSION_GRANTED"; // this will be an arg to the above method
    private final static String PERMISSION_DENIED = "PERMISSION_DENIED";

    public static String getPermissionStringFromEnumInt(int permissionEnum) throws Exception
    {
        switch (permissionEnum)
        {
            case 0:
                return Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
            // "and the rest is still unwritten" - Natasha Bedingfield
        }
        Log.e("NoodlePermissionGranter", "Error. Unknown permissionEnum " + permissionEnum);
        throw new Exception(String.format("Error. Unknown permissionEnum %d",permissionEnum));
    }

    public static void grantPermission(Activity currentActivity, int permissionEnum)
    {
        // permission enum must match ordering in NoodlePermissionGranter.cs
        final Activity act = currentActivity;
        Log.i("NoodlePermissionGranter","grantPermission " + permissionEnum) ;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            Log.i("NoodlePermissionGranter","Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23 (" + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT+")");
            UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(UNITY_CALLBACK_GAMEOBJECT_NAME, UNITY_CALLBACK_METHOD_NAME, PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = permissionEnum;
            final String permissionFromEnumInt = getPermissionStringFromEnumInt(permissionEnum);
            if (currentActivity.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permissionFromEnumInt) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i("NoodlePermissionGranter", "already granted");
                UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(UNITY_CALLBACK_GAMEOBJECT_NAME, UNITY_CALLBACK_METHOD_NAME, PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                return;
            }

            final FragmentManager fragmentManager = currentActivity.getFragmentManager();
            final Fragment request = new Fragment() {

                @Override public void onStart()
                {
                    super.onStart();
                    Log.i("NoodlePermissionGranter","fragment start");
                    String[] permissionsToRequest = new String [] {permissionFromEnumInt};
                    Log.i("NoodlePermissionGranter","fragment start " + permissionsToRequest[0]);
                    requestPermissions(permissionsToRequest, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
                }

                @Override public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults)
                {
                    Log.i("NoodlePermissionGranter", "onRequestPermissionsResult");
                    if (requestCode != PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE)
                        return;

                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                        // contacts-related task you need to do.
                        Log.i("NoodlePermissionGranter", PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(UNITY_CALLBACK_GAMEOBJECT_NAME, UNITY_CALLBACK_METHOD_NAME, PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                    } else {

                        // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                        // functionality that depends on this permission.
                        Log.i("NoodlePermissionGranter",PERMISSION_DENIED);
                        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(UNITY_CALLBACK_GAMEOBJECT_NAME, UNITY_CALLBACK_METHOD_NAME, PERMISSION_DENIED);
                    }


                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.remove(this);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                    // shouldBeOkayToStartTheApplicationNow();
                }
            };

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(0, request);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            Log.w("[NoodlePermissionGranter]", String.format("Unable to request permission: %s", error.getMessage()));
            UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(UNITY_CALLBACK_GAMEOBJECT_NAME, UNITY_CALLBACK_METHOD_NAME, PERMISSION_DENIED);
        }
    }

}
```

BuildNoodlePermissionGranter.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
ClASSPATH=$UNITY_ROOT"/Unity.app/Contents/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Variations/mono/Release/Classes/classes.jar"

javac NoodlePermissionGranter.java -bootclasspath $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platforms/android-23/android.jar -classpath $ClASSPATH -d .
javap -s com.noodlecake.unityplugins.NoodlePermissionGranter
jar cvfM NoodlePermissionGranter.jar com/
rm -rf com
```

You need project.properties and a dummy AndroidManifest.xml in order to have Unity package a jar outside of Plugins/Android/libs

project.properties

```
target=android-9
android.library=true
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.noodlecake.unityplugins.noodlepermissiongranter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
</manifest>
```

It'd be nice if the PermissionRequestCallback supplied the requested permission enum as a parameter, but UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage only supports a single string argument and I decided not to implemented the string serialization (using JSON to do this would be a good choice).

Comment: So this is intended to pop up the permission request window? What If I need it approved at install time, say for a gearVR app?

Comment: If you use targetSdk=23 you have to request at dangerous permissions at runtime, they are not granted on install. Look up runtime permissions on Android 6 if you want more info

Comment: This is awesomely helpful!!! Thanks a lot for posting! Saved me huge amount of time. Checked - works as posted.

Comment: This is also the first normal human readable tutorial as for how to easily write android plugins for Unity. Awesome!
Please add to description: A developer has to make sure that permissions being requested with this code MUST be as well declared in main AndroidManifest of unity project. Issues arise otherwise. Plus - JVM used to compile the jar must match the one configured in Unity.

Comment: Thanks tomurka. Glad it helped. I couldn't find any good resources on this so when I figured it out I knew I had to write about it on Stack Overflow. Btw, there's a bug. If the SDK < 23, it shouldn't return, it should call the permission granted callback. I'll edit this to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Its is very helpful and is exactly what i needed. I'm having one issue though and was wondering if you or anyone else seen it also. After granting WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE runtime it doesn't seem to take effect until i kill the app. Reading online i found lots of misleading informations people saying you have to restart an app for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to work, some people saying it's a bug, some people saying it just works for them with no restart. Have you seen anything like that before? I'm running it on Nexus 6 with 6.0.1

Comment: I've used WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE without an app restart to save screenshots to the sdcard in a Unity game. Haven't tried on that exact device, however.

Comment: Where should we put the Java file? I notice it isn't listed in the project structure.

Comment: The Java file isn't necessary in the Unity Project, just the .jar is. Put the Java file (and the build script) in your project anyways (something like Plugins/Android/NoodlePermissionGranter/Java/) so you can see the source, and recompile the .jar if you need to.

Comment: Thanks @JasonKnight in advance although I didn't use this plugin yet but still after reading comments I am pretty much that it would work for me also but Can I use this plugin with other plugins like I am already using plugins like IAB Billing and Analytics related plugin in my game so I was just wondering would it work fine with them? Secondly does this plugin override Activity or not ? Thanks again and I hope you would help me out as well :)

Comment: or one more thing is it possible for you to just send me android studio project or the even the jar only that could save my time and I'll be very thankful to you :) @JasonKnight

Comment: one more thing what change would I be making in android manifest file at Unity's side?

Comment: Im currently trying to implement this but in android studio it complains about the "final Fragmen request = new Fragment()" part saying "Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static".
Im not a java dev so i dont really know what to do to fix this :/

Comment: the classpath has changed [using Unity 2017.1]

new one is "/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Variations/mono/Release/Classes/classes.jar"

Comment: acimaz I hit the same issue and am trying to adjust things to work according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260604/fragments-should-be-static-such-that-they-can-be-re-instantiated-by-the-system will post an answer if it works

Answer (score 6):

Another addition to Jason's excellent code for Unity 5.3.3 and up (I'm using 5.4), I added this to the manifest to block Unity from automatically asking at launch:

```
 <application>
     <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog" android:value="true" />
 </application>
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Jason Knight's post (which I used for my own Unity plugin for handling runtime permissions):

I used Android studio for creating a plugin. I followed the directions on the following site and worked perfectly: http://www.thegamecontriver.com/2015/04/android-plugin-unity-android-studio.html

I also added another method using the shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() function so I'm able to hide certain UI elements if the user denied the permission and checked the "Don't ask again" checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers (especially Jason Knight's) have been super helpful to me, but I had to adjust the code to get it to work, so I'm sharing those changes here.

As noted in the comments, that code has this error in Android Studio: `final Fragment request = new Fragment();` part saying "Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static"

Now I'm not a Java expert so maybe I did things wrong, but I tried to adjust things as explained here: [Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260604/fragments-should-be-static-such-that-they-can-be-re-instantiated-by-the-system)

Mostly, I split the Fragment into a new class, so that it's not an anonymous class. So now there are two Java files:

```
package com.synapse.unityplugins;

import android.Manifest;
import android.os.Build;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;

public class PermissionGranter {
    public final static String UNITY_CALLBACK_GAMEOBJECT_NAME = "SynapsePlugin_listener";
    public final static String UNITY_CALLBACK_METHOD_NAME = "permissionRequestCallbackInternal";
    public final static String PERMISSION_GRANTED = "PERMISSION_GRANTED";
    public final static String PERMISSION_DENIED = "PERMISSION_DENIED";

    // only implemented WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE so far
    public static String getPermissionStringFromEnumInt(int permissionEnum) throws Exception
    {
        switch (permissionEnum) {
            case 0:
                return Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
            // "and the rest is still unwritten" - Natasha Bedingfield
        }
        Log.e("PermissionGranter", "Error. Unknown permissionEnum " + permissionEnum);
        throw new Exception(String.format("Error. Unknown permissionEnum %d",permissionEnum));
    }

    public static void grantPermission(int permissionEnum)
    {
        final Activity act = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;
        Log.i("PermissionGranter","grantPermission " + permissionEnum) ;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            Log.i("PermissionGranter","Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23 (" + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT+")");
            UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(UNITY_CALLBACK_GAMEOBJECT_NAME, UNITY_CALLBACK_METHOD_NAME, PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            return;
        }

        try {
            final String permissionFromEnumInt = getPermissionStringFromEnumInt(permissionEnum);
            if (act.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permissionFromEnumInt) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i("PermissionGranter", "already granted");
                UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(UNITY_CALLBACK_GAMEOBJECT_NAME, UNITY_CALLBACK_METHOD_NAME, PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                return;
            }

            final Fragment request = PermissionRequestFragment.newInstance(permissionEnum);
            final FragmentManager fragmentManager = act.getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(0, request);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            Log.w("PermissionGranter", String.format("Unable to request permission: %s", error.getMessage()));
            UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(UNITY_CALLBACK_GAMEOBJECT_NAME, UNITY_CALLBACK_METHOD_NAME, PERMISSION_DENIED);
        }
    }
}
```

That's the main plugin class, and here's the fragment:

```
package com.synapse.unityplugins;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;

public class PermissionRequestFragment extends Fragment {
    public static PermissionRequestFragment newInstance(int permissionEnum) {
        PermissionRequestFragment frag = new PermissionRequestFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("requested", permissionEnum);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        int permissionEnum = getArguments().getInt("requested");
        final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = permissionEnum;

        try {
            final String permissionFromEnumInt = PermissionGranter.getPermissionStringFromEnumInt(permissionEnum);
            String[] permissionsToRequest = new String[]{permissionFromEnumInt};
            Log.i("PermissionGranter", "fragment start " + permissionsToRequest[0]);
            requestPermissions(permissionsToRequest, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (Exception error) {
            Log.w("PermissionGranter", String.format("Unable to request permission: %s", error.getMessage()));
            UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(PermissionGranter.UNITY_CALLBACK_GAMEOBJECT_NAME,
                    PermissionGranter.UNITY_CALLBACK_METHOD_NAME, PermissionGranter.PERMISSION_DENIED);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i("PermissionGranter", "onRequestPermissionsResult");
        int permissionEnum = getArguments().getInt("requested");
        final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = permissionEnum;
        if (requestCode != PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE)
            return;

        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // permission was granted, yay! Do the task now
            Log.i("PermissionGranter", PermissionGranter.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(PermissionGranter.UNITY_CALLBACK_GAMEOBJECT_NAME,
                    PermissionGranter.UNITY_CALLBACK_METHOD_NAME, PermissionGranter.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        } else {

            // permission denied, boo! Disable the functionality that needed it
            Log.i("PermissionGranter", PermissionGranter.PERMISSION_DENIED);
            UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(PermissionGranter.UNITY_CALLBACK_GAMEOBJECT_NAME,
                    PermissionGranter.UNITY_CALLBACK_METHOD_NAME, PermissionGranter.PERMISSION_DENIED);
        }

        final Activity act = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;
        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = act.getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.remove(this);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

And for completeness here's the C# within Unity:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class SynapsePlugin : MonoBehaviour {

    // subscribe to this callback to see if your permission was granted.
    public static Action<bool> PermissionRequestCallback;

    // for now, it only implements the external storage permission
    public enum AndroidPermission {
        WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    }

    public static void GrantPermission(AndroidPermission permission) {
        if (!initialized)
            initialize ();

        PermissionGranterClass.CallStatic ("grantPermission", (int)permission);
    }







    //////////////////////////////
    /// Initialization Stuff /////
    //////////////////////////////

    private const string PLUGIN_LISTENER_NAME = "SynapsePlugin_listener"; // must match UnitySendMessage call in Java

    // it's a singleton, but no one needs to know about it. hush hush. dont touch me.
    private static SynapsePlugin instance;
    private static bool initialized = false;

    static AndroidJavaClass PermissionGranterClass;
    private const string PERMISSION_GRANTED = "PERMISSION_GRANTED"; // must match Java
    private const string PERMISSION_DENIED = "PERMISSION_DENIED"; // must match Java

    // runs automatically when making calls, or can pre-init manually
    public static void initialize() {

        // add object to scene
        if (instance == null) {
            GameObject go = new GameObject();
            go.name = PLUGIN_LISTENER_NAME;

            // instance will also be set in awake, but having it here as well seems extra safe
            instance = go.AddComponent<SynapsePlugin>();
        }

        // get the jni stuff
        new AndroidJavaClass("com.synapse.unityplugins.PermissionGranter");

        initialized = true;
    }

    public void Awake() {
        DontDestroyOnLoad (this.gameObject);

        // instance is also set in initialize.
        // having it here ensures this thing doesnt break
        // if you added this component to the scene manually
        instance = this;

        if (name != PLUGIN_LISTENER_NAME)
            name = PLUGIN_LISTENER_NAME;
    }

    // we're calling this method from the java side.
    // the method name and gameobject must match Java's UnitySendMessage
    private void permissionRequestCallbackInternal(string message) {
        bool permissionGranted = (message == PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        if (PermissionRequestCallback != null)
            PermissionRequestCallback(permissionGranted);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi sorry to bring this back up, but i have used your code to ask for permissions in my app, and its pretty much working now. But please could you help me to understand how the Action<bool> works? Where it says "subscribe to this callback to see if permission granted". I tried to use it like any bool to see if it granted, but it doesnt work like that (Cannot convert Action<bool> to bool). Casting didnt work either so I clearly have it completely wrong lol

Comment: Action<bool> is a delegate that takes a boolean argument, not a boolean itself. In other words, you give it a method to call like so: `SynapsePlugin.PermissionRequestCallback += OnPermissionRequest` where there is a method `private void OnPermissionRequest(bool granted)`

Comment: thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I kinda get it.... But on your code, what Method is this calling? if (PermissionRequestCallback != null)
            PermissionRequestCallback(permissionGranted);    ////(NOTE: That is at the very bottom of your code)

Comment: btw i put debug.Log("message = " + message); and I get PERMISSION_GRANTED, so I know im more than halfway there lol.. is it worth me making it into a full question so you can answer it properly and i can mark it as answer? I guess not as people dont like duplicate-ish questions

Comment: The method called is OnPermissionRequest (or whatever you assigned to that action). In other words, calling PermissionRequestCallback is *actually* a call to whatever methods have been assigned; an Action is basically a variable that stores a *function* (ie. a function pointer) rather than int or string or whatever. I highly recommend you look up delegates to understand how they work.

Comment: thanks again for explaining. I have watched and read lots since on delegates but still using it in practice is hard for me. I finally got your code to work for me, but still cant quite see where OnPermissionRequest is doings its magic from. I am going to research much more and hopefully will understand soon enough. Thanks for your help

Comment: No magic, it's just a method that takes a boolean argument. Just as some other part of your game calls GrantPermission in the plugin, some other part also assigns a method to PermissionRequestCallback

Comment: Id love to say I fully understood but I dont quite get what that final call to the Action<bool> actually does. i see that it will be true if PERMISSION_GRANTED, but cant for the life of my see what that does and how, lol, I'll keep trying as its important to me to understand it

Comment: i will watch a video on it for a simple example and hopefully ill get it soon :) thanks again dude +1

Answer (score 2):

I've used Jason knight's answer to create [this plugin](https://github.com/Jimmar/Permission-Please) that does the job, the whole code is available on the github repo.

There is also unity package file for easy integration.